# Converting this Python code into a visual GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface

I have a python code that a friend made , as I have very small knowledge of python..
I want to convert it into a GUI as we will distribute the code as a program for it to be beginner-friendly .

anyways here's the code:

```
import time, os, sys 
try: 
if len(sys.argv) < 2: 
    fn = raw_input("Enter the name of the file you want to edit: ") 
else: fn = sys.argv[1] 
f = open(fn) 
b = f.read() 
for i in b[:300]: 
    print hex(ord(i))[2:], 
f.close() 
line = str(0x15c)+'-'+str(0x15f) 
if len(sys.argv)<3: 
    hexcode = raw_input("3 bytes color hex number: ") 
else: hexcode = sys.argv[2] 
if not hexcode.startswith('0x'): 
    hexcode = '0x'+hexcode 
hexstr = '0x'
start = int(line.split('-')[0]) 
end = int(line.split('-')[1]) 
for i in b[start:end]: 
    hexstr+=hex(ord(i))[2:] 
ascii = '' 
for i in range(2,len(hexcode),2): 
    char = chr(int(hexcode[i:i+2],16)) 
    ascii+=char 
b = b[:start]+ascii+b[end:] 
for i in b[:300]: 
    print hex(ord(i))[2:], 
except Exception, x: 
print x 
time.sleep(3) 
finally: 
f = open(fn,'wb') 
f.write(b) 
f.close()
```

Now I found this on a tutorial but don't know how to use it:
    #simple GU0I

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("BreffHexReplace")
root.geometry("400x200")

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
label = Label(app, text = "This is a label!")

label.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Any help?
thanks!

also one more thing , in this code , after I type in the name or the replacor hex , it shows me a list of hex , how can I make it not shown?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this program is so simple, you can try EasyGui( easygui.sourceforge.net/ ). To start, add `import easygui as eg`. This line loads the EasyGui module. Next, replace `fn = raw_input("Enter the name of the file you want to edit: ")` with `fn = eg.fileopenbox(title = 'HexReplace', msg = 'Browse to the file you wish to edit')`. This opens a box to browse to the wanted file. Also replace `hexcode = raw_input("3 bytes color hex number: ")` with `hexcode = eg.enterbox(msg = '3 bytes color hex number', title = 'HexReplace')`. This pops up an input box. Replace `print x` with `eg.msgbox(title = 'HexReplace', msg = x)`. This shows a message box with the exception. The `title` argument is the window title. To remove the hex list, add between the imports and the `try` block: `null = open(os.devnull, 'W's); oldstdout = system.stdout; sys.stdout = null`
This will silence all print messages.

Comment: @thethiny: What line number did Python say the error occurred at?

Comment: I said nvm it worked , I forgot to add fn=
thanks anyways,,, can you help with this>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856173/python-display-a-hex-color-that-can-be-changed